# angular как сделать include html в другой html файл?

Tags: angularjs, angular2, typescript, ionic, ionicframework

есть проект на ionic 3, как подключить html шаблон к другому html файлу? файлы находятся в одной директории. Делаю так:

```
<ion-header>
    <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</ion-header>
```

но это не работает. Подскажите где ошибка

Comment: напомнили мне старый добрый эсэсай `<!--#include file="included.html" -->`

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko , не совсем понял вас, можете написать подробнее куда это вставить, я так понимаю это коммент обычный?

Comment: напиши полный путь к файлу от корня приложения